# VB.net Variable in String Being Ignored

Tags: vb.net, git

This code gets a Git `fromHash` and `toHash` and then diffs them.  The line that is commented out does produce the correct Git statement.  I can take that result and run it myself and get the correct diff results.  But when the `diff = MyUtilities.RunCommandCom...` runs it, it seems to be ignoring the last `toHash` variable because it returns everything from `fromHash` to current.  I have verified that also.  Why would this be happening?  I have tried `fromHash & " " & toHash` also.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fromHash As String
    Dim toHash As String
    Dim diff As String

    fromHash = MyUtilities.RunCommandCom("cd " & repoBox.Text & " & ""c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"" rev-list -n 1 " & fromTagBox.Text, False)
    toHash = MyUtilities.RunCommandCom("cd " & repoBox.Text & " & ""c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"" rev-list -n 1 " & toTagBox.Text, False)

    'resultsLabel.Text = "diff --name-only " & fromHash & " " & toHash
    diff = MyUtilities.RunCommandCom("cd " & repoBox.Text & " & ""c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"" diff --name-only " & fromHash & Space(1) & toHash, False)

    resultsLabel.Text = diff

End Sub
```

Comment: To try narrowing down the problem, try outputting the whole string that out are sending to `RunCommandCom` to a .BAT file and then run the .BAT file just to rule out the possibility that the two commands you are running are losing something in translation of copy & paste.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN, Thanks.  Outputting to a file showed me that the `toHash` was on another line.  So the code to obtain the `fromHash` must have been returning a CR or LF at the end.  I changed them both to `fromHash.Trim & Space(1) & toHash.Trim` and it works.  Ugh.  Rookie mistake.  Thanks!